# Semisimple iff every maximal right ideal is a direct summand

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show that a ring $R$ is a right semisimple ring if and only if every maximal right ideal if $R$ is a direct summand of $R$.

A ring is right semisiple, if every right ideal is a direct summand, so the if part is clear. For the only if part I know, that every ideal is contained in a maximal ideal, but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $T$ be a right ideal of $R$. By a routine application of Zorn's Lemma, you can show that there exists a right ideal $N$ maximal with the property $T\cap N=\{0\}$.

You can easily argue why $T\oplus N$ is an essential right ideal of $R$ (that is, it intersects every nonzero right ideal nontrivially.)

Now suppose that $T\oplus N\neq R$. You know that there exists a maximal right ideal $M$ of $R$ containing $T\oplus N$. But now, a right ideal which contains an essential right ideal is essential itself. But an essential right ideal which is also a summand must be $R$ itself, a contradiction.

Therefore you had $T\oplus N=R$ to begin with.

---

One natural generalization to take away from this discussion is that *a maximal submodule is either a summand or an essential submodule.*

Comment: Thanks! We haven't covered essential ideals, so I didn't have the idea to prove it like that, but this answer is really helpful!

Comment: @mathstackuser I'm glad it was close enough to what you know to be helpful! Since this is the solution that leaps to mind for me, I have a hard time thinking about more elementary solutions. If I think of one, I'll post it here.